# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. while calling a simple route

Tags: laravel

I am using this route laravel 5.5 
/names/origin/1

and route defined for this uri is follows

```php
Route::get('/names/origin/{id}',function(){
    return "here";
});
```

but instead of hitting this uri and error thrown saying
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Try adding  `$id` as a  parameter to your anonymous function

Comment: tried but having same issue

Comment: even if I change from /names/origin/{id} to /names/origin/{origin} still having error saying id not exist should not it has to change error to [origin] does not exist

Comment: and if I change both uri and route to /names/origin/something/{id} it starts working and I dont have any other route matching /names/origin. any hint why is that happening

Comment: how do you access that route, post the request also1

Answer (score 0):

Initially the flow of parameters must be checked that is  passed through the view. And try this,

```
Route::get('names/origin/{id}','ControllerName@Function');
```